# Как достать ссылку из content='link'?

Tags: python, парсер, lxml

Допустим, существует элемент:

```
<meta property="og:audio" content="https://freesound.org/data/previews/611/611605_1648170-lq.mp3" />
```

Как мне получить в переменную `https://freesound.org/data/previews/611/611605_1648170-lq.mp3`

Answer (score 1):

```py
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup as Soup


response = requests.get('https://freesound.org/people/NoiseCollector/sounds/55157/')
soup = Soup(response.content, 'html.parser')

# Если python 3.8 и выше то можно записать так
url = meta.get('content') if (
    meta := soup.find('meta', property='og:audio')
) else None

#Если версия python ниже чем 3.8, то как написано выше работать не будет. Можно так
url = None
meta = soup.find('meta', property='og:audio')
if meta:
    url = meta.get('content')


print(url)
#https://freesound.org/data/previews/55/55157_4948-lq.mp3
```